# Using filter to find email addresses matching a domain

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to find email addresses in O365 Exchange that matches a particular domain using PowerShell.

If I use:

```
Get-Recipient -ResultSize unlimited -filter '(PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*smith*")' | fl primarysmtpaddress
```

I get all the addresses that have the string

If I use:

```
Get-Recipient -ResultSize unlimited -filter '(PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*@domain*")' | fl primarysmtpaddress
```

I get no results.

It looks like nothing is matched after the @.

I want to use `-filter` rather than a where statement because it is so much faster.

Comment: Try inverting the quotes (switch `"` with `'` and vice versa). It may be a quoting issue

Comment: I have never found a way to do this. I can't say for certain, but I feel like PrimarySMTPAddress is a special, calculated property based off of other data. Wildcards seem to work until the domain is added. I know this is not what you want to hear, but you could filter against EmailAddresses first and then do the dreaded `where`.

Comment: Is there any difference if you use `-match` instead?

Comment: @trebleCode it appears that `-Match` is not an acceptable operator in the OPath filter. Even `-clike` is not accepted either.

Comment: You shouldn't need the parentheses.  How about not using the '@'?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue. It seems to be related to the the specific attribute you filtered on, "PrimarySMTPAddress".

I was able to get the filter statement to return results by changing it to leverage "EmailAddresses", another attribute the email address is stored in:

```
Get-Recipient -ResultSize unlimited -filter '(EmailAddresses -like "*@domain*")' | fl primarysmtpaddress
```

Something else I saw of note: the "filterable properties" documentation mentions avoiding using "PrimarySMTPAddress" for another reason that I didn't know of:

> Don't use the PrimarySmtpAddress property; use the EmailAddresses property instead. Any filter that uses the PrimarySmtpAddress property will also search values in the EmailAddresses property. For example, if a mailbox has the primary email address dario@contoso.com, and the additional proxy addresses dario2@contoso.com and dario3@contoso.com, all of the following filters will return that mailbox in the result: "PrimarySmtpAddress -eq 'dario@contoso.com'", "PrimarySmtpAddress -eq 'dario2@contoso.com'", or "PrimarySmtpAddress -eq 'dario3@contoso.com'".

*Source*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/filter-properties?view=exchange-ps